# How to interpret 'e' in Yamane's Formula?

Tags: sample-size, descriptive-statistics, population

If I use e=0.05, and from Yamane's formula I obtain, say, a sample size of 300 from given population size. Now, for instance, I obtain some descriptive statistics from the sample size such as the mean value of educated farmers is 20%.
Can I interpret 'e' in this context is as I am 95% confident that the mean of the educated farmers in the population is 20%. or interchangeably, on average the number of educated farmers in the population is 20% (+ - 5%): i.e, (20%+5%) & (20% -5%). so technically between 15% and 25%.

The formula I used is:`n = N/(1+N (e)^2)`

```
n =  sample size
N = Total population size
e = precision level 5% (0.05):
```

Or does that mean, ' the sample size of 300 (±5%) truly/accurately represents the given population size?

Comment: Please edit your question to give & explain the formula you're referring to. (It's entirely possible that someone writes it with *f* instead of *e*, or uses *e* for another variable).

Comment: Hello Monica, I have added a photo of the formula, I am not sure If it is visible to you or not?

Comment: That hasn't worked. In any case, I'd suggest typing the formula, using LaTeX if you know it - for the sake of visually impaired people using screen readers, among other reasons.

Answer (score 2):

`e=0.05` transforms a sample's value to ±5% of the population's value.

This is how `e` is interpreted in Yamane/Cochran formulae. See the excerpt and reference below for an explanation on the *error margin's* use and interpretation.

NB: All other statistical/data collection procedures should be correct for that interpretation (assumption) to be true.

> The **level of precision**, sometimes called **sampling error**, is the range
> in which the true value of the population is estimated to be. This
> range is often expressed in percentage points, (e.g., ±5 percent).
>
> Thus, **if a researcher finds that 60% of farmers in the sample** have adopted a recommended practice **with a precision rate of ±5%**, then he or she **can conclude that between 55% and 65%** of farmers in the population have adopted the practice.

Source: *Israel, G. D. (1992). Determining sample size. Fact Sheet PEOD-6. University of Florida.* ([pdf](https://scholar.archive.org/work/o7xz4dciyncylke2r7myrw3yzy/access/wayback/http://sociology.soc.uoc.gr/socmedia/papageo/metaptyxiakoi/sample_size/samplesize1.pdf))